# F# compiler complaining with "undefined" when element is out of a `fun` scope

Tags: lambda, f#, closures, anonymous-function

I have this function which doesn't compile:

```
let RunningProcessesFromUser(username: string) =
    let header::processes = SplitStringInLines (HiddenExec "ps" "aux")
    let procElements(proc: string) =
        proc.Split([|' '|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    List.filter(fun proc -> username.Equals((procElements proc).[0])) (processes)
```

And the compiler is telling me:

```
error FS0039: The namespace or module 'username' is not defined
```

So, inside my `fun` block I cannot use variables from the outter scope?

I tried to change it like this, to use what I believe is **partial application**, but it still gives me same error:

```
let RunningProcessesFromUser(username: string) =
    let header::processes = SplitStringInLines (HiddenExec "ps" "aux")
    let procWasSpawnedByUsername (user: string) (proc: string) =
        let procElements = proc.Split([|' '|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        user.Equals(procElements.[0])
    List.filter(procWasSpawnedByUsername username) (processes)
```

Also, another question, is the correct topic here "lambda", "closure", or "anonymous-function", or all of them?

Thanks

Comment: Is that supposed to be `List.filter(fun proc -> username.Equals((procElements proc).[0])) processes`? As it is, you're passing `String.Equals` a `string[]` then trying to index into a `bool`.

Comment: oops yeah sorry, fixing

Comment: In your 'partial application' code you're still doing `username.Equals(procElements.[0])` rather than `user.Equals(procElements.[0])`. That being said, your original code looks just fine and I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work (assuming all types are what they appear to be).

Comment: oh true, but if I fix that, I still get the same error on the next line

Comment: my guess - the `list.filter` is indented slightly less than the rest of the function.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you please provide a minimum example that should compile, but doesn't? The above code doesn't compile since it's lacking definitions its depends on, but the error that `username` is not defined doesn't seem to be among them. This type of closure should definitely work.